# Sequelize: Associating two columns in one table. After i added my associations i am getting an error when inserting a row

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, psql

Thanks in advance!

So i am getting an error every time i try to insert a new row into my table. Before i added my associations i tested my table and my create function in postman and was able to successfully insert into the table. The problem only came once i added my associations. Here are my tables and associations

```
id | userOneId | userTwoId | status | actionUserId |         createdAt          |         updatedAt
```

Here are the associations

```
  models.relationship.belongsTo(models.user,  {as:"userOne", foreignKey:"userOneId"})
  models.relationship.belongsTo(models.user,  {as:"userTwo", foreignKey:"userTwoId"})
  models.user.hasMany(models.relationship, {as:"userOne", as:"userTwo"})
```

Once i added the associations every time i try to insert a new row i get this message from the database then the error at the end

> Executing (default): INSERT INTO "relationships" ("id","userOneId","userTwoId","status","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING "id","userOneId","userTwoId","status","actionUserId","createdAt","updatedAt","userId";
> DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: column "userId" does not exist

As well my catch statement hints at

> 

```
code: '42703',
hint: 'Perhaps you meant to reference the column "relationships.userOneId" or the column "relationships.userTwoId".',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a little more digging in the Sequelize docs, I found the issue. Had to flip the foreign Key from the relationship  to the user

> models.relationship.belongsTo(models.user, {as:"userOne",})
> models.relationship.belongsTo(models.user, {as:"userTwo",})

> ```
>   models.user.hasMany(models.relationship, {foreignKey:"userOneId", foreignKey:"userTwoId"})
> ```